Django has a slow import time when using Poetry instead of PIP
I used PIP and poetry in the same project. I also use importtime-waterfall to check import time when running the application (run manage.py file).
With case-use Poetry, Django takes more importing time (x2, x3) than case-use PIP.
Can you help me explain it? Or give me related documents. Thank you so much !!!

Please provide details on how exactly you've installed what where and how you're running the benchmark.

Share the benchmark results, without any technical details, it is (close to) impossible to determine the reason. If the duration is exceptionally short, this might even just be aliasing with the clock update.
